# Can I delete old hook_update_N functions?

Tags: nodes, updating

Suppose you have a custom module, and you have `hook_update_N()` implementations in your `.install` file.

If you have old update functions, and all updates have run in all sites that the module is installed, is it safe to delete those functions? 
Please note this is about custom modules that you have access to all sites and updates have been run.

Thank you in advance and I wish everyone a merry Christmas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you can be sure that they will never be needed it is safe to delete them.

Definitely make sure that you have made any changes required in the main install sections before removing the `hook_update_N` section.

If possible use some form of version control so you have clear record of the changes if you find you have missed upgrading that module on a site it will be super easy to restore that section for a one-off update.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is a situation where you could need to keep the older update hooks: when you restored the database from an old backup and you need to update the database to the latest version of the installed modules.
If that is never your case, then—as long as you are sure all the sites have been updated to the same version of the module—you can remove the old update hooks. Keep in mind that, if you delete an update hook you needed for a site, the alternative is uninstalling the module, and then install the latest version, but this will cause data loss.

Updates hooks are **only** invoked when updating an installed module, and they are not invoked contemporarly to `hook_schema()` and `hook_install()`. When a module is installed, `hook_update_N()` is not invoked; `hook_schema()` and `hook_install()` are **only** invoked when a module is installed. That is the reason why old `hook_update_X()` could be removed, once a module is updated to version X or older.

Usually, the update hooks are removed when passing from a Drupal version of the module a more recent one (e.g. from the Drupal 6 module to the Drupal 7 module). Since the installation file is loaded just on updating and installing (and other limited situations), removing the update hooks doesn't give any significant gain.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the other answers, but I'm answering the questions with some of of my findings.

When you define the database schema in a `hook_schema`, that should be **always** the latest version of the database. For other hooks, such as `hook_install` and `hook_enable`, it's same. All 3 hooks should use the latest functionality as you are installing the module afresh.

Schema version is stored in the `system` table, along with the module name. 
To answer my own question, yes I can remove old `hook_update_N()` functions if I'm sure all sites already have the update.

You can skip update numbers, and Drupal still can figure out the upgrade steps. 
If your scheme version is `7004`, and the module's `.install` file contains only `hook_update_7009`, only the `7009` will be called. See [`update_get_update_function_list`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!update.inc/function/update_get_update_function_list/7). 
Also, you can implement [`hook_update_last_removed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_last_removed/7) to inform Drupal about updates that are no longer available, and it will look for greater update `N`s.

Comment: Indeed, `hook_schema()` needs to use the latest schema of the database, since it is called instead of `hook_update_N()` when the module is being installed, and not updated. Drupal doesn't care for the update numbers; it just runs the update functions starting from the ones with the lower number.